# Google Sheets formulas not working on data imported using ImportJSON

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some numerical data in my google sheets which is imported using ImportJSON.gs:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14mfMx89qLq4NhYtGFI-MH4TVJIiRxKdS72saEVP38Rk/edit?usp=sharing

The data shows fine inside the sheet, but when I try to apply any formula to the data i.e. =Sum(D7:D8) , the result is always wrong.

It appears that the formula always considers the data to be 0, even though the actual displayed number may be anything in the data cell.

However, if I type =D7+D8 the correct result is displayed in the formula cell. Any Chart on the imported data range is also displaying "No Data" when I try to plot it.

I have tried Number.parseFloat in the script, but the final result in the formula cell is still wrong.

Comment: When I saw your script, what is `MyLib`?

Comment: MyLib is a library which includes get_url() function for retrieving the url of the resource. I can't share that url because a license is required. It is not necessary to have the url for solving this problem.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I could correctly understand about your situation and replicate it, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize for my poor skill.